# how to add public ssh key on GPC TPU vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu

I am on WSL ( Windows Subsystem for Linux) and willing to set up gcloud CLI. While authenticating getting error of "Can not launch a browser"

Comment: Please share more details. How did you create this machine? It's `TPU VM` or `TPU NODE`? Did you use default compute engine ServiceAccount or custom? Did you try to use `--no-launch-browser` flag? Is this full error output?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to login from WSL to Linux VM (TPU) on GCP. How you are doing this? Using Putty, RDP, Terminal? In general, [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys) you have guide how to create SSH key and how to add SSH key to VM